# Htaccess Unicode URL Issues

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

This is my htaccess file:

```
IndexIgnore *

ServerSignature Off

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

LimitRequestBody 10240000

IndexIgnore *.wmv *.mp4 *.avi *.pdf

AddType 'text/html; charset=UTF-8' html

Options All -Indexes +MultiViews +FollowSymLinks

ErrorDocument 400 /Pocnimo/400/
ErrorDocument 403 /Pocnimo/403/
ErrorDocument 404 /Pocnimo/404/

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?a-site.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://(www\.)?a-site.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)//(.*)$
RewriteRule . %1/%2 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?a-site.com [NC]
RewriteRule \.(css)$ - [NC,F,L]

# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^a-site\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.a-site.com/$1 [R=permanent,L]

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/gif A2592000
ExpiresByType image/jpg A2592000
ExpiresByType image/png A2592000

<FilesMatch "\.(htaccess|htpasswd|ini|phps|fla|psd|log|sh)$">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
ExpiresActive Off
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(pl|php|cgi|spl|scgi|fcgi)$">
Header unset Cache-Control
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 1 month"  
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 2 days"
</IfModule>

<ifmodule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/Icon\.ico [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} Icon\.ico    [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.a-site.com/Icon.ico [R=301,L]
</ifmodule>

<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Connection keep-alive
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<Files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</Files>

<IfModule mod_php4.c>
php_value zlib.output_compression 16386
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_php5.c>
php_value zlib.output_compression 16386
</ifModule>

<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckSpelling Off
CheckCaseOnly Off
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(htm|html|php)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
BrowserMatch MSIE ie
Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge, Chrome=1" env=ie
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://www.a-site.com"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?a-site\.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(gif|jpg)$ http://www.a-site.com/Ulaz?otvori=Zabrana [R,NC,L]
</ifModule>
```

I wanted the URL to be as `www.a-site.com/Š?term=Šaram`

But instead I get: `www.a-site.com/Š/?term=Šaram` and therefore page can not be found although the paths are good. Any solution to this? The url with the file that points to the "www.a-site.com/Š?term=Šaram" is "/Š?term=Šaram"... But does not help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL rewriting with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16388959/url-rewriting-with-php)

Comment: @Rohit416 It's not. It works fine with files with any other letter, e.g. www.a-site.com/S?term=Silva

Comment: No answer, close this then ...